# What is the best way to send xml data to a web service rather than using CDATA?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I have a web service that takes a single string parameter.

In my case I need to send a string which is an xml document where one of its elements contains an xml fragment (which I will use to create a file).

So for example I am sending:

```
<people>
  <person>
     <name>J Smith</name>
     <value><![CDATA[<content>rest of xml document here</content>]]></value>
  </person>
</people>
```

I used .. to create an xml file.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this rather than using CDATA?. The CDATA files are very small (less than 20KB).

JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use CDATA. You can pass the xml fragment directly as is.

See, for example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480498.aspx

UPDATE:

Steve pointed out that you have a string parameter not XmlElement parameter. I'm not sure if it would still work that way (though I feel like it could :).

Another option besides CDATA and Base64 would be Xml encoding, e.g.

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
var node = xml.CreateElement("root");
node.InnerText = "<content>Anything</content>";

var xmlString = node.InnerXml; /// &lt;content&gt;Anything&lt;/content&gt;
```

Comment: Probably the web method he has takes a string, not an xml element... and since we've already agreed we should be constrained by his existing implementation....

Comment: +1 XML encoding is better than CDATA in my opinion... although I think it's just that; an opinion. Not sure there are many legitimate arguments for one being better than the other.

Comment: @Frantisec: Thanks for the two solutions. Also thanks to Steve for your input.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest Base64-Encoding the XML fragment.

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted this... the answer seems legitimate to me. I've seen this done all over the place. I personally have a different suggestion, but this one still seems valid.

Comment: Would there be any benefit in base64 encoding the content since my string parameter (<people><person>..</person><person>....etc</people>) will not be too big (less than 400KB at max)?

Comment: I believe he's suggesting you base64 encode the part you're currently using cdata for (the value in your "value" element).

Comment: +1 Best answer - and strictly meets the requirements without changing the service contract or technology.

Comment: @Steve. Yes, I understood the encoding was referring to the CDATA parts in the <people> xml. In all with multiple CDATA sections I do not expect the xml block to be more than 400KB so I was concerned if it was an overkill (performance wise) doing encoding/decoding?

Answer (score 1):

How about a standard HTTP POST using Mutipart/Form-Data ? Make the single parameter part of the url or querystring.

This is the more "RESTful" way of doing things.

It's just a standard file upload.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, does it.

Comment: How not? He has a web service which "takes a single string parameter" ("name", from his example), and an XML document (which he is putting inside another XML document using CDATA). He's asking for a better way... I say just upload the XML document in the CDATA as a normal document, and pass the single parameter ("name") in the URL/Querystring... seems like it answers the question perfectly to me.

Comment: He was asking about the way to put XML data inside XML document. (I guess that's because he's using SOAP not REST.)

Comment: Never once did he say that. I don't know where you got that from. Quote?

Comment: Yes, it is a soap based web service.

Comment: "I need to send a string which is an xml document where one of its elements contains an xml fragment". And he already *has* the web service.

Comment: @JD, There is nothing non-standard about file uploads. You can do it with a single line of code in .NET using WebClient: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @František Žiačik, you got me there. Although I don't really see how that furthers the discussion. If what he's got isn't working well for him, maybe he should consider an alternative. If he or you don't like my answer just move along. No harm done.

Comment: @Steve : Although I need to use the web service as it is, I am still trying to get my head around this. Would I have to create a new hosted service on the server or use the existing one (i.e. the web service currently is http://localhost:2948/PeopleWebService.asmx/Execute)?

Comment: @Steve : Please continue, more options I have the more I have learnt. Thanks.

Comment: There are any number of ways to do it. If you're not using WCF (which it looks like you aren't given the .asmx you cited) the simplest way is probably just to make an aspx page and in page_load do the standard asp.net upload submission processing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx WCF makes this even easier and will support response messages more naturally in JSON, POX, SOAP, or just about any other format you want.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for the lesson :). Unfortunately I have to use the web service as it is but I have more options for future projects.